# Eclipse - Search for a word or Phrase inside the package

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way I can "find a particular word or phrase" in a package/project(in all files in the package/project), without going to each and every class file and do the `ctrl + F` thing.

Let's say I have a template project for schools. I just need to change the school's name with the needed name. I know I can keep this as a constant and do, but I am just giving you a scenario.

My requirement is that I find all files where the particular pharse or word exists in the package and change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Search` -> `Search...` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. There is `File Search` where you can search by text or regular expression and restrict search by scope and/or file name patterns. And there is `Java Search` which allows you to find declarations, references and occurrences of Java elements.